# Malicious ERC20 blocking batch withdrawals of tokens (e.g. ERC777)

Tags: solidity, attacks, solidity-0.7.x, call-depth-attacks

I was wondering whether the following attack vector is possible in practice.

There's a batch transfer function that is intended to batch transfer the tokens owned by the contract. That function distributes the tokens according to a particular order and checkpoints the user balance data too.

What if one of the tokens in the middle is a malicious ERC777 ERC20-like token? And the hooks it calls on transfer are exploited by the receiver in a way that somehow spends all the available gas.

Will that cause a denial of service?

Apologies for being pretty vague. Hopefully, you get what I mean in my question.